# Save and retrieve Intent from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, json, android-intent, sharedpreferences, uri

In my app I need to save Intend data for later use (on app relaunch).
What I've tried is:

**To save:**
Parse `Intent` into `Uri` to get `String` >> Put `String` in `SharedPreferences`

**To Retrieve:**
Get `String` from `SharedPreferences` >> Use obtained `String` to parse it into `Intent`

This is my code to save and retrieve Intent

```
private void saveIntent(Intent data){
    editor = prefs.edit();
    String uri = data.toUri(0); //intent.toURI() deprecated
    editor.putString("INTENT_DATA", uri);
    editor.commit();
}

private void retrieveIntent(){
    String intentString = prefs.getString("INTENT_DATA", null);
    try {
           mIntent = Intent.parseUri(intentString, 0);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried this approach but it returns Empty. I've tried to debug the code and found that this is because, in `saveIntent()` method, `data.toUri(0)` assigns 'Empty String' to `String uri`

Please tell me where am doing something wrong, and please do mention if there is some other way to store Intent object with all data bound to it.

I've searched internet and found that parsing into JSON could be a way, but most of the people who tried that approach complaint about losing unknown data that is bundled with Intent object in result of some activity.

And please mention if it is really possible to save Intent object at all or not?? If there exist any way, please guide me to that approach.

Comment: Have you got the answer yet? can you help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: @hungcuiga1 This is an old question and no I found no way during that time, I ended up using some other approach to handle my case

Comment: do you remember which method to use? Thank you.

Comment: actually, I did not save/retrieve intent from shared preferences, instead, I saved the extra data

Comment: where is extra data? is it from `data:intent?` ?. where did you save it? please help me.

Comment: You use intent extras to pass data between activities.
This is how you put extra data: `intent.putExtra(YOUR_KEY_HERE, YOUR_DATA_HERE)`.
And this is how you retrieve it: `getIntent().getExtras().getString(YOUR_KEY_HERE)`.
And then save the retrieved data in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Please post a separate question with your current implementation

Comment: no one answered me. Please help me.

Comment: I tried but don't work,maybe i miss anthing this is my action ,can you take a look at it? Thank you so much: 
`val intentx:Intent =ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(this,resultCode,data)` 

`public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {`         `Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScreenCaptureService.class);`         `intent.putExtra(ACTION, START);`
`intent.putExtra(RESULT_CODE, resultCode);`
`intent.putExtra(DATA, data);`
`return intent;     }`
and i save `intentx.getExtras()?.getString("DATA")`

Comment: this link my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012331/put-intent-to-sharedpreferences-return)

Comment: I edited [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012331/put-intent-to-sharedpreferences-return). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#9398) you see that your `Intent` must either have the flag `URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME` or `URI_INTENT_SCHEME` set, or have it's `data` URI filled out.

I personally never done something like this, but I guess if you have an explicit intent with no data URI attached, you need some of the flags to have it converted to some string representation.

Comment: Drill down into your `Intent` that you're trying to serialize - it might have too little information to actually be serializable. Compare what you have in there with what the implementation dictates that should end up in the string.

Comment: when intent parsed to uri with flag `Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME`, it returns string "intent:", that means it is missing all the intent extras

Comment: In general, I recommend implicit (ie. URI-driven) instead of explicit (ie. activity-class-referencing) intents. This will help modularization at a later point greatly (because you no longer need a class reference in module A from module B just because you want to navigate from some A activity to B) and should even help you with your current issue.

Comment: Wrt intent extras you'll have a hard time serializing those completely anyways - the extras is basically a `Bundle` data structure that accepts any simple type _and_ `Parcelable`s and `Serializable`s - how do you think should such data be encoded in some URI string? That would be just wrong :)

Comment: Yeah I've understood your point .. so should i try to parse the Intent into a JSON string?? and use that String later to recreate the Intent? Do you think if this approach is valid?