# Put intent to sharedPreferences return ""

Tags: android

Hello I have a `mediaproject` service. I start it with `startActivityForResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {
        if (requestCode == com.robertohuertas.endless.MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val bundle = data?.extras
                if (bundle != null) {
                    for (key in bundle.keySet()) {
                        Log.d("TAGTAGTAGTAGTAGTA_st", key + " : " + if (bundle[key] != null) bundle[key] else "NULL")
                    }
                }
//                GlobalConstant.datax=data;
                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                    PREFS_KEY_intent, MODE_PRIVATE
                )
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                val uriString: String = data!!.toUri(requestCode)
                editor.putString(PASSWORD_KEY_intent, uriString)
                editor.commit()
                Log.d("main_asssssssss","bolssss "+uriString)
                startService(
                    com.robertohuertas.endless.ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(
                        this,
                        resultCode,
                        data
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to save `intent` and use it after phone reboot but i can't get in `onActivityResult`
The result of `Log.d("TAGTAGTAGTAGTAGTA_st"` is `android.media.projection.extra.EXTRA_MEDIA_PROJECTION : android.os.BinderProxy@6bb5fa5`
,but result of `Log.d("main_asssssssss","bolssss "+uriString)` is `D/main_asssssssss: bolssss` don't have see `uriString`,it is "". where is my wrong?

**NEW**

I try as @muhammad-shuja this code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {
         val intentx:Intent=ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(this,resultCode,data)
```

`ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent` is:

```
public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.robertohuertas.endless.ScreenCaptureService.class);
        intent.putExtra("ACTION", START);
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_CODE", resultCode);
        intent.putExtra("DATA", data);
        return intent;
    }
```

I saved value `intentx.getExtras()?.getString("DATA")` to `sharedPreferences`

```
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
val xsd=intentx.getExtras()?.getString("DATA")
editor.putString(PASSWORD_KEY_intent, xsd)
editor.commit()
```

`BroadcastReceiver`

```
class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val PREFS_KEY_intent = "myPreferncesintent"
    private val PASSWORD_KEY_intent = "myPreferncesintent"
    var telApp: Intent? =null

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
//        Toast.makeText(
//            this@StartReceiver,
//            "Tải mô hình không thành công onOrientationChanged！",
//            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
//        ).show()


        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED && getServiceState(context) == ServiceState.STARTED) {
            val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY_intent, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val password = sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD_KEY_intent, "")
            try {
                telApp = Intent.parseUri(password, 0)
            } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (telApp!=null){
            val audioCaptureIntent22=com.robertohuertas.endless.ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(
                context,
                Activity.RESULT_OK,
                telApp
            )

        context.startService(audioCaptureIntent22)}
    }
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: Here `intent.putExtra(DATA, data)` you are trying to pass whole intent as an extra, it will not work, instead, it will pass only the reference. If you want to pass its extras you first need to get the bundle of extras from the first intent and then attach that bundle to the second intent, do it like this. `intent.putExtras(data.getExtras()))`

Comment: On the receiving end to get the data you need to use the keys of extra data of first intent.

Comment: 'intent.putExtra(DATA, data)' is code to i get intent to start service. And after reboot i will restart service. it is nice work to start i can't change it. How to save data:intent? in `onActivityResult` . i will up date `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: @MuhammadShuja How to do it,to be honest i just started android for two months. sorry there's so much I don't know.

Comment: The above comments can help you get the extra data attached to an intent only. But what you are trying to do is not possible, because you can't save a whole intent in sharedpreferences for later usage. Android uses Binder Inter-process Communication Framework for Intents. This mechanism does not allow what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @MuhammadShuja does it mean i can't start mediaproject service after reboot phone? I feel sad, thank you very much.

Comment: you must find some other approach, I just told you that it's not possible to save and retrieve intents from sharedpreferences on reboot, you should look for some other ways to solve your problem, never give up!