# View logcat of application after boot android

Tags: android, logcat

Hello i create a app with a service will start after reboot phone but after reboot phone, app can't start,it have error. How i can see logcat to find error like when i connect my phone to pc and view logcat in android studio

Comment: hi, whats the error ? can you share pls

Comment: @ZaidZakir is [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012331/put-intent-to-sharedpreferences-return)